# Django : Why should I add package name inside INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: python, django

In Djano, why should I add third-party package names inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` for some packages such as [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/install.html), [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation), [debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.0/installation.html) etc, while I don't want to add for some packages such as [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) etc ?

I couldn't figure out why should add them to a specific list, even though they all are similar `pip packages` and I installed them in the same way. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because they are Django apps. Celery and requests are not Django apps, they are separate Python libraries.

Comment: Kind of `re-usable apps` ?

Answer (score 4):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/) :

> Package? App?
>
> A Python package provides a way of grouping related Python code for
>   easy reuse. A package contains one or more files of Python code (also
>   known as “modules”).
>
> A package can be imported with import foo.bar or from foo import bar.
>   For a directory (like polls) to form a package, it must contain a
>   special file **init**.py, even if this file is empty.
>
> A Django application is just a Python package that is specifically
>   intended for use in a Django project. An application may use common
>   Django conventions, such as having models, tests, urls, and views
>   submodules.

From above statements we understand that every well-written python code could be a package, now if this package is a bunch of python code in a directory, installing it would mean just copy the directory in your project and `import` them wherever needed in code.

But now there is this package which was already a django app and maybe used some special advantages of being one. Like exposing a restful API or delivering some sort of static resources or even working with special django-specific classes. these kind's of operation's need your direct permission in `settings.py` so that your project will know how to deal with this package. or even they may require to include their url path's to your project so that people visiting your site could access them.

I assume all this manual job is an act of security.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add apps with models(non-abstract), templates, templatetags or management commands so that django-admin finds and loads them